# ECS cluster scale in / out tasks based on CPU/memory

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I have a problem statement. Can anyone answer it for me.

> You have a Microservice running in your ECS cluster.
> How would you manage below tasks. (Use terraform)
>      a. You want to scale in/out the tasks based on CPU/Memory utilisation
>      b. You want to scale in/out the tasks based on the requests made to the service

Comment: Having others do you assignments hopefully gets you nowhere: [Show what you tried, where specifically you are stuck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin i was able to configure cpu/memory utilisation using terraform with the solutions you gave, there was a specific module for the same, but couldnt get idea about the second one.

Comment: For the second one you need load balancer associated with your ECS service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling of ECS services on Fargate is explained in:

- [How can I configure Amazon ECS Service Auto Scaling on Fargate?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-service-auto-scaling/)

> a.You want to scale in/out the tasks based on CPU/Memory utilisation

You use `ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization` or `ECSServiceAverageMemoryUtilization`.

> b.You want to scale in/out the tasks based on the requests made to the service

You use `ALBRequestCountPerTarget`.